# SSRS Filter Expression by date range

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an expression that outputs the number of rows: `=CountRows("DataSet1")`.
I want to filter it by date range using parameters in order to output the number of rows within that range.
I have tried this: `=CountRows(IFF Fields!DATE_OF_REQUEST.Value, "DataSet1" >= Parameters!startDate.Value 
AND Fields!DATE_OF_REQUEST.Value, "DataSet1" <= Parameters! endDate.Value 
("DataSet1"))`

How can I achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient solution, but, is the way I go about making date range reports:

I would apply the date range in the where clause of your dataset:

```
WHERE Date_of_Request between @startDate and @endDate
```

For this, I would create another identical dataset that just looks at distinct records and apply the where clause to get the most accurate figure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the logic in your COUNTROWS expression is correct here...

What you need to do is evaluate each row and if it matches you criteria return 1 else return 0 then sum the results of this. So you can modify you expression slightly like this.

```
=SUM(
    IIF(
        Fields!DATE_OF_REQUEST.Value >= Parameters!startDate.Value 
        AND Fields!DATE_OF_REQUEST.Value <= Parameters!endDate.Value,
        1,
        0,
        "DataSet1"
       )
    )
```

I'm doing this from memeory so the position of the scope `"DataSet1"` might be incorrect.